# Difference of Columns in Two Files Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, enumerate

I have two files similar to file1 and file2 and I'm trying to compute the difference for each column and saved it to out.
Examples of files and desired output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPQcY.png
I've tried using pandas and a few other methods but couldn't get it. This is what I have so far, thanks:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

files = [sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]]

f1 = open(sys.argv[1])
lines = f1.readlines()
f1.close()
df1 = pd.DataFrame(file1,columns = ['A_1','B_1','C_1']

f2 = open(sys.argv[2])
lines = f2.readlines()
f2.close()
df2 = pd.DataFrame(file2,columns = ['A_2','B_2','C_2']

df1['Difference'] = np.where((df1['A_1'] - df2['A_2']),(df1['B_1'] - df2['B_2']),(df1['C_1'] - df2['C_2']))
print (df1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use numpy:

```
f1 = np.loadtxt(sys.argv[1])
f2 = np.loadtxt(sys.argv[2])

dif = f2 - f1
```